# Powershell: Null Array Exception in passing args to Remote Session

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to run a command on a remote session but I am getting a

> Cannot index into a null array.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
>       + PSComputerName        : serverName

I have checked all the arguments that I am passing to the remote session and none of them are  null. Following is the command:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process $args[0] -ArgumentList $args[1] -RedirectStandardOutput $args[2] -RedirectStandardError $agrs[3]} -Args $Consoledir,$arguments,$stdOutLog,$stdErrLog;
```

I am using this command to run a console application that is passed in the $dir argument (D:\Temp\console.exe). This application further takes some arguments that are passed in the $arguments parameter.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: `$agrs[3]` => `$args[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Param($dir, $args, $outlog, $errlog)    
    Start-Process $dir -ArgumentList $args -RedirectStandardOutput $outlog -RedirectStandardError $errlog
} -ArgumentList $Consoledir,$arguments,$stdOutLog,$stdErrLog;
```